# Add List of Inserted Id's to generic sObject List

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, sobject, invocable-method, insert

I need to replicate the standard "Create Records" Flow Element in an Invocable Apex Class so that I can include some additional code before and after the insert.
I am using generic sObject Lists as both the request input and result output.  I can successfully insert the records from the input sObject List.  However I cannot figure out how to take the List of successfully inserted Id's and add them to the output sObject List.  Below is my code

```
    public without sharing class CustomInsert {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static List <Results> execute (List<Requests> requestList) {
        
        List<SObject> inputCollection = requestList[0].inputCollection;
        
        
        //CUSTOM BEFORE CODE HERE
        
            Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(inputCollection);

        //CUSTOM AFTER CODE HERE
        
        List<Id> insertedIds = new List<Id>();
            for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                insertedIds.add(result.getId());
            }
        }
        
        Results response = new Results();
        Response.outputCollection = insertedIds;

        responseWrapper.add(response);
        return responseWrapper;    
    }
    
    public class Requests {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Input' required=true)
    public List<SObject> inputCollection;
    }
    
    public class Results {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Output' required=true)
    public List<SObject>  outputCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `Id` value into a record of the correct type (as all instances must have a specific type) and assign the record the `Id` using this pattern:

```
    List<SObject> inserteds = new List<SObject>();
    for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            SObjectType t = result.getId().getSObjectType();
            SObject r = t.newSObject(result.getId());
            inserteds.add(r);
        }
    }
```

and then assign the list directly.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked liked a charm